# Есть ли Javascript сервисы, позволяющие делать запись видео с вебкамеры и отправлять его на облачное хранилище?

Tags: javascript, видео, web-camera

Нужен сервис, с `API`, который имеет возможность доступа к веб-камере устройства. Чтобы пользователь мог записать видео, которое отправится на сервер и вернет мне ссылку. Или скажите в какую сторону рыть?

То есть грузишь на страницу скирпт, который спрашивает доступ к вебкамере. Если ты разрешаешь, то там можно нажать кнопку "записать", происходит запись. После того, как ты остановил, выгружаешь запись на облако (а лучше автоматически выгружается) и падает ссылка. Есть подобное `API`?

Comment: То есть грузишь на страницу скирпт, который спрашивает доступ к вебкамере. Если ты разрешаешь, то там можно нажать кнопку "записать", происходит запись. После того, как  ты остановил выгружаешь запись на облако (а лучше автоматически выгружается) и падает ссылка. Есть подобное API?

Comment: Копай в сторону `video API`...  смотри  тут    http://docs.videojs.com/index.html

Comment: нашел такое...
[Захват изображения с камеры в браузере с помощью getUserMedia](http://html5.by/blog/html5-image-capture-getusermedia-stream-api-mirror/)

Answer (score 3):

Если под камерой устройства вы подразумеваете камеру подключённую к компьютеру или встроенную камеру ноутбука, то вам нужен сервис трансляций.

Большая часть таких сервисов платная, но есть и бесплатный вариант. Гугл трансляции.

https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard

В данном случае вам надо будет создавать закрытую трансляцию, и просто никому ссылку для просмотра не давать. После записи, запись автоматически будет доступна по ссылке в облаке Google.

Там есть разные варианты трансляций, либо через специальную кодек-утилиту, его надо будет дополнительно скачать. Либо через Google hangouts, это самый простой вариант. Но подойдёт ли он для таких целей сказать не могу...

Если вы имеете ввиду скрипт который вы хотите поставить на свою страницу, то скорее всего бесплатный версий такого нет, аналогичные программы если есть то достаточно дорогие и сложные в разработке. И тут одной JavaScript не обойтись, а нужна полноценная клиент-серверная платформа.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне нужен полноценный скрипт, который грузится на страницу и позволяет пользователю записать видео. Хотел найти open source аналог вот этому https://addpipe.com/

Answer (score 1):

существуют методы позволяющие захватить видео с веб-камеры или подобного устройства, можно сохранить на клиенте и потом отправить куда-то в облако думаю

Comment: Можете скинуть пару примеров?